# C++11 is_pod with GCC 4.6

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

Under the [relaxed definition of POD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Modification_to_the_definition_of_plain_old_data) in C++11, it is my understanding that the following struct is considered a POD:

```
template <class T>
struct Foo 
{
    Foo()
    { }

    explicit Foo(T* obj) : m_data(obj)
    { }

    T* m_data;
};
```

However, using GCC 4.6 and compiling with the `-std=c++0x` flag, if I say:

```
std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_pod<Foo<int>>::value << std::endl;
```

It outputs:

```
false
```

Here is an [**ideone link**](http://ideone.com/7yTq46) showing the full program.  (Note that ideone uses GCC 4.5)

So, is my understanding of PODs in C++11 mistaken, or is GCC 4.6 simply not up-to-date in terms of C++11 compliance?

Comment: FWIW: GCC 4.7.1 (tested with a home-brew build on Mac OS X 10.7.5; compiler line `g++ --std=c++11 -O3 -g -Wall -Wextra x.cpp -o x`) also says `false`.  That's a data point; not any sort of answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A POD struct must be a trivial class (C++11 §9[class]/10):

> A POD struct is a non-union class that is both a trivial class and a standard-layout class, and has no non-static data members of type non-POD struct, non-POD union (or array of such types).

§9[class]/6 defines what a trivial class is:

> A trivial class is a class that has a trivial default constructor and is trivially copyable.

§12.1[class.ctor]/5 defines what a trivial default constructor is.  It begins:

> A default constructor is trivial if it is not user-provided and...

The default constructor of `Foo<T>` is user-provided and is therefore nontrivial.  Therefore, `Foo<int>` is not POD.  It is, however, standard layout.

Comment: So, standard layout simply means that you can safely cast a Foo pointer to a pointer to the first data member?

Comment: @Channel72 Yes. For more information check this [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_standard_layout#Notes).

Comment: @Channel72 Standard layout actually gives a few more guarantees. Essentially, it guarantees that the data is packed in a way compatible with a `struct` with the same members defined in C.

Answer (score 2):

Default declaring default constructor, makes Foo a POD.
i.e.

```
Foo() = default;
explicit Foo(T* obj) : m_data(obj)
{ }
```

http://ideone.com/vJltmA